# How to reinit Kotlin Object class in unit test with Junit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, junit, mockito

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class MyObjTest {

lateinit var myObj: MyObj

@Before
fun setup() {
    myObj = MyObj
    // I need reset myObj variable to default
}

@Test
fun test1() {
    assertTrue(myObj.items==0)
    myObj.items+=2
}


@Test
fun test2() {
    assertTrue(myObj.items == 0) 
    //Do Something
    // Here its failing, as in **test1** value is getting incremented by to.
}

}
```

```
object MyObj{

    var items = 0

   //Some functions
}
```

I am having a Kotlin Object class with many fields and methods.

I need to perform unit tests for the methods inside the object class and need to verify fields in the object.

Before running each test function in the test file, I need to reset the whole object class data to default.
Now I am manually updating every field in the @Before function. I am trying to find a better way to handle this. But I couldn't able to find a direct way to reinit object class data in the `**@Before**` annotated function.

Here manipulating data in one test affects other test functions as it tried to check with a manipulated object.

> The requirement is to have the Object instance instantiated to the default value before running the test.

Comment: I think this looks like a bit of an XY-problem, and the simplest option is to convert `MyObj` to a class, so you can instantiate a fresh instance for each test.

Comment: I agree with the above answer - an object is a singleton and therefore cannot be automatically reset (if you really want to you can add a `reset()` method but that's not a great solution IMHO)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. Converting to normal class is not possible for my current use case. The only is to reset manually. I actually thought that there would be an actual solution/ workaround.  Will try to find any other approaches.

Comment: There isn't any way to reset an object, because it's not the way you're supposed to solve this problem.